# CKEditor can't edit the content

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So I'm having a strange bug since I'm using the CDN of CKEditor. The editor appear perfectly but I can't click on the editor to write something. However every other functionality are working.
I've added `contenteditable="true"` just in case but there is no signifiant changement.

This is my html and src :

```
<textarea name="content" id="content" contenteditable="true">
     {{$article->content}}
</textarea>
<script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );</script>
```

`<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>`

Do I have to add something in the javascript? Btw there is no error in the console.

Comment: have a look to console errors: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: @Mr.George what is it suppose to be ? I have no error in my console as I've said.

Comment: did you ever get this to work? I've been having this problem for over a year and haven't found a solution

Comment: @bowlerae sadely not, I've gave up and created a specific pages without bootstrap